# Is there a way to reformat CMD's DIR /W command output such that I doesn't show Volume Info?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, directory, formatting

I want to output all .wad and .zip files in a folder in columns. I want only the filenames. Here is how I did it:
`dir /w *.wad *.zip`
And here's the output:

```
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is SOME-NUMBER

 Directory of C:\Users\user\folder


 Directory of C:\Users\user\folder

file1.wad   file2.wad   file3.wad   file4.zip   file5.zip
file6.wad   file7.wad   file8.wad   file9.wad

              99 File(s)    999.999.999 bytes
               9 Dir(s)  999.999.999.999 bytes free
```

What I want:

```
file1.wad   file2.wad   file3.wad   file4.zip   file5.zip
file6.wad   file7.wad   file8.wad   file9.wad
```

Essentially just the filenames in columns without any extra information.
Is there a solution that I can put in a .bat Batch file?

I tried formatting with FOR %F to no luck. I'm not knowledgeable on CMD commands... I searched the Web for a solution but found none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a `For` loop, (as you say you'd tried), you would simply decide to exclude all results from the command which have a space character at the left End Of the Line. If you open a Command Prompt window, type `for /?` and press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key, it will show you all of the options available, (including the `EOL` option), so not being knowledgeable on the command should not be a factor.

From within a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```bash
@For /F "EOL= Delims=" %%G In ('Dir *.wad *.zip /W 2^>NUL') Do @Echo %%G
```

Directly within [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd):

```bash
For /F "EOL= Delims=" %G In ('Dir *.wad *.zip /W 2^>NUL') Do @Echo %G
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dir /w |findstr /vbc:" "
```

should do as you ask - finding all lines of `dir/w` that `/v` do not contain `/b` at the beginning, a space. Note that the swiches `/v` and `/b` can be combined, hence `/vb`.

Comment: @Compo : Yes, my bludner. Didn't test it as usual machine is sick (now recuperating) and standby machine has neither my test setup nor a decent monitor.